# Can I write browser plugins with Python?

Tags: java, python, browser-plugin

I'm thinking about writing a browser plugin, but I don't know any C.
Can I write browser plugins with Java or Python?

I was thinking... All those websites store cookies on my browser to identify me.
If I wrote a plugin that would supply a browser GUID in the http headers, webservers could identify the browser.

I think that would rule out the need for 99% of all the cookies, pretending for a moment that all users and servers use it.

Comment: Pretending that all users would install your plugin is way too much. Not even Java or Flash have an install base that large. Even pretending that 1% of people would install it is quite too far. Besides, with the concerns upon privacy, most people wouldn't want a GUID being sent on every request... I surely wouldn't.

Comment: Interesting idea.  A GUID isn't perfect; it can be spoofed.  Someone could use your MAC address and knowledge of the last GUI you created to generate GUID's that would appear to be you.

Comment: Being able to uniquely identify the browser is probably the main thing people don't like about cookies.

Comment: I wasn't really planning on getting everyone to use it, just sort of a proof of concept. I was just thinking about a way to do what cookies do without cookies. Most cookies just contain some sort of session ID, if I could replace that with one global ID... That would be just as easy to spoof as a session ID I think. You could include some sort of policy like cookie managers to decide which website may access the GUId or store a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly write an ActiveX plugin for IE in Python using the win32com interfaces. But you'd have to install Python and [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) along with your plugin for it to work, so it'd be pretty bulky. I don't think it's going to be popular to install all that just to get a GUID.

(Actually most people specifically *don't want* a GUID. Is that really your only aim? If you're thinking about single-sign-on options, look at systems like OpenID as used on SO... this gives the user much greater control.)

Comment: I use Mac, so that is not an option. I'm not sure if PyObjC can do this... Maybe I should learn C or XUl for Firefox.

Comment: Writing an add-on with XUL and JavaScript would be the path of least resistance, if you only need to support Firefox. Add-ons are much less hassle than actual plugins.